# Access function inside closures in javascript using event on html page?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to access function on event handler which is inside a closures. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eodyr3dc/)

```
(function(){
var val="balahhh"
function a(){
    alert(val)
}
})
```

Comment: Not that I know of ... that's the strength of the closure.  The only way would be to provide a connection to some variable in the Global scope.

Comment: No. You want to make your function variable global, or use [proper event attachment](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can attach it to `window` object but that would pollute global scope. But nonetheless

```
(function () {
    var val = "balahhh";
    window.a = function() {
        alert(val)
    }
})(); // call it
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eodyr3dc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper events in your example:

```
(function () {
    document.getElementById('your-id').addEventListener("click", a);
    var val="balahhh";
    function a(event){
        alert(val)
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})();
```

And in your html, just assign an id to your link (or target all link elements, as you wish):

```
<a href="#" id="your-id"></a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7449ye4x/1/)

Comment: Why prevent the event from propagating? The question was how to attach event handlers, which you did, but you also unnecessarily added functionality the OP didn't specify.

Comment: Good points, thanks. It was just how I usually handle events that should only trigger once.

Comment: Just going to mention this here; You can also just add events to parent elements (body for example) and check which child/sub-child element the event originated from. This allows to more easily implement complex functionalities without having to worry too much about event order and propagation.